# How can I to solve $ \cos x = 2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I would like to get an approx. solution to the equation: $ \cos x = 2x$, I don't need an exact solution just some approx. And I need a solution using elementary mathematics (without derivatives etc).

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+cos%28x%29%3D2x

Comment: @HansLundmark I need to present some solution not just giving some numbers from some computer.

Comment: Hint: Do a Taylor series expansion of $\cos x$ (say, up to order 6) on the left and then solve for x in the remaining equation. Now, explain this approach and figure out how to select the right value and what the error is. Regards

Comment: try using the fact that $ |\cos x| \le 1 $ and $ \cos (-x) = \cos (x)$

Comment: @gen: The word "solution" is ambiguous. It can mean both the value of $x$ which satisfies the equation, and the procedure for finding that value. When you say "an approx. solution", I think most people will interpret this as just the number, so if you want the procedure you should perhaps have said so in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a pocket calculator, start with $0$ and repeatedly type [cos], [$\div$], [2], [=]. This will more or less quickly converge to a value $x$ such that $\frac{\cos x}2=x$, just what you want.

Comment: Or [$\cos$], [$2$], [$/$] if you are using an [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculator.

Comment: @robjohn just imagine if this question was deleted!.

Comment: Make sure you've got it set on RADIANS, not DEGREES.

Answer (score 0):

At small angles $\alpha ≈ sin\alpha$, so at the equation we can write $2 sin\alpha≈ cos \alpha$. From that $tan \alpha ≈ 1/2$. The solution to the last equation is less than a degree off the exact solution to the original equation.

Answer (score -2):

if $\cos x=2x$ which means 
$$x=\frac {1}{2.22131587} \,\mathrm{rad},$$

$$x=28.65957881\,\mathrm{Grad},$$

$$x=25.79362093\,\mathrm{Degree}$$

**point:**
$$\cos x=1-\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^4}{4!}-\frac {x^6}{6!}+\cdots$$

$0 < x < +\frac {1}{2.5}\,\mathrm{rad}$ because $\cos x=2x$

---

This is also a mathematical method, i mean Estimate the amount through math without using a computer or calculator!.

$$\cos x \simeq 1-\frac {x^2}{2!}=2x,$$

$$x^2+4x-2=0,$$

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

where the $a=1$ and $b=4$ and $c=-2$ then $x\simeq 0.45$

Comment: I need some reasing...

Comment: What method did you use to get the approximate solution?

Comment: I've written a complex computer program for solving these equations.

Comment: How is this supposed to help? The two upvoters might want to explain, as well.

Comment: base on Series Rules

Comment: Neo: Sorry? *What* is based on *what*?

Comment: @did Forget computers and calculators, I add new answer through a mathematical method

Comment: For this approach to be helpful, it should provide bounds on the error between the number proposed and the true solution.