# Interval in which the root of the trigonometric equation lies.

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

A trigonometric equation is given such that
$$\sqrt{1 + \frac{3\cos2x}{{\sqrt {\sin^4x+4\cos^2x}} + \sqrt{\cos^4x+4\sin^2x}}}=\sqrt2 \sin^{-1}(\sin2x)$$ $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$

It is to be proven that one of the roots of this equation lies in the interval $(\frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{\pi}{6})$.

I took the subset $[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}]$ so that $sin^{-1}(sin2x)=2x$ holds true. Now I squared both sides to obtain
$$ \frac{3\cos2x}{{\sqrt {\sin^4x+4\cos^2x}} + \sqrt{\cos^4x+4\sin^2x}}= 8x^2-1 $$

With another small manipulation,
$$ {\sqrt {\sin^4x+4\cos^2x}} - \sqrt{\cos^4x+4\sin^2x}= 8x^2-1 $$

How should I proceed after this? Also what is the total nuber of solutions to the above equation?

Comment: $$\sin^4x+4\cos^2x=(1-\cos^2x)^2+4\cos^2x=(1+\cos^2x)^2$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I reduced using your help and obtained $cosx=2x$. Can this be reduced further?

Comment: First of all, $$\sqrt{\cos^2x}=|\cos x|$$ and $$\sin^{-1}(\sin2x)=2x$$ only if $$0\le2x\le\dfrac\pi2$$  So only in   $0\le2x\le\dfrac\pi2,$ $$\cos x=2x$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275198/how-can-i-to-solve-cos-x-2x

Comment: i have found $$x=\frac{1}{2}\sin(\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  I did not understand how is this particular value of $x$ obtained.

Comment: by squaring and simplifying

Comment: i think this equation has eight real solutions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  Can you please mention upto what power should I take the Taylor series  to get those solutions?

Comment: Would it not be enough to show that the two sides are continuous on the interval and at $\pi/8$ one side is higher while at $\pi/6$ the other side is higher? This can only occur if there is a root in between. There may be more roots, but you didn't say you had to prove exactly one root.